Help with Durrett exercise 2.4.2
I'm working on Durrett Exercise 2.4.2:

Let $X_0=(1,0)$ and define $X_n \in \mathbf{R}^2$ inductively by declaring that $X_{n+1}$ is chosen at random from the ball of radius $\left|X_n\right|$ centered at the origin, i.e., $X_{n+1} /\left|X_n\right|$ is uniformly distributed on the ball of radius 1 and independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. Prove that $n^{-1} \log \left|X_n\right| \rightarrow c$ a.s. and compute $c$.

I would like to define $r_n=\frac{|X_{n+1}|}{|X_n|}$ and show that $\left\{r_n\right\}$ is pairwise independent (i.e. $r_n$ and $r_m$ are independent for any $m\ne n\in \mathbb{N}^+$) and identically distributed so that I can use the following strong law of large numebr (theorem 2.4.1 in Durrett)

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be pairwise independent identically distributed random variables with $E\left|X_i\right|<$ $\infty$. Let $E X_i=\mu$ and $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$. Then $S_n / n \rightarrow \mu$ a.s. as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

So far I have checked that $\left\{r_n\right\}$ are identically distributed and have a common distribution function $F$ given by
$$F(t)=\begin{cases}0, & t< 0\\t^2, & 0<t<1\\1,&t\geq 1\end{cases}$$
so it remains to show that they are pairwise independent, or in other words for any $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $P(r_n\leq a, r_m\leq b)=P(r_n\leq a)P(r_m\leq b),$ but I have no idea on calculating the probability left hand side. How can I compute this probability? Any help is appreciated!

In the exercise, we already have that $X_{n + 1}/\vert X_n \vert$ is independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. Thus $r_n$ is independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. For any $n, m$, and WLOG, we can assume $n < m$, then, since $r_m$ is independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_m$ and $r_n$ is a function of two of these random variables ($X_{n + 1}$ and $X_n$), so $r_n$ and $r_m$ must be independent.

How do we obtain that $X_{n+1}/|X_n|$ is independent of $X_1, ..., X_n$ ?

@Tiffany It's given in the exercise. "... and independent of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. Prove that ..."

Oh I missed this! Thank you so much!
